# Trying to download CSV file, and output as XML with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, csv, download

I would very much like to download a CSV file, and output it as XML.
I can make it work if I download the CSV and store it in a file, and then read it and convert it to xml, but I would very much like to skip saving the CSV file, and just keep it in a variable.

So far I have:

```
$headers = "a,b,c,d,e,f"
$url = "verylongurl"

$csvfile = Invoke-WebRequest $url | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
Write-Output $csvfile
```

That will show the CSVfile I'm after, so it's in the variable as I want.
If I save it, I can convert it with

```
Import-Csv -Path "file.csv" -Header a,b,c,d,e,f | export-clixml c:\temp\out.xml
```

But I really don't want to go through a filesave first.

I then tried with:

```
ConvertFrom-Csv -InputObject $csvfile -Header $headers | export-clixml c:\temp\out.xml
```

But that outputs the headers followed by the first field in each line? So I guess that is not the way to do it :-)
I feel like I'm really close, can anybody please help me the last step?

Ok, I found some answer to it, not sure why, but if I write the headers directly on the line, it exports the xml to a file:

```
ConvertFrom-Csv $csvfile -Header a,b,c,d,e,f | export-clixml c:\temp\out.xml
```

now instead of writing it to a file, I would like to just return the xml file.
So I tried using

```
ConvertFrom-Csv $csvfile -Header a,b,c,d,e,f | convertto-xml | Write-Output
```

, but that just gave me an empty XML file.

Comment: As for the headers problem: `-Header` expects an _array_ of column names, whereas `"a,b,c,d,e,f"` is a _single string_; use `"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"` instead.

Comment: Also note that `Export-CliXml` and `ConvertTo-Xml` result in _different_ XML representations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what your goal is. I really don't understand the purpose of exporting CSV data as a PowerShell object with `Export-Clixml`. That seems like taking a useful, generic data file format (CSV) and converting it into a domain-specific XML file format (CLI XML) intended for serialization between PowerShell sessions.

However, this should work:

```
Invoke-WebRequest $url | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content |
    ConvertFrom-Csv -Headers $headers |
    ConvertTo-Xml |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty OuterXml
```

Comment: The goal is to import it into prtg that can handle xml files, but not csv's :-( I will try it out, thankyou!